# Confused as to how $pullAll works in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I've got a document that looks like this:

```
db.blog.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4dc1c938c4bfb4d21a000001"),
        "blogid" : 1,
        "body" : "Lorem ipsum dolor",
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "id" : 1,
                        "name" : "Alex",
                        "comment" : "Test",
                        "approved" : 1
                },
                {
                        "id" : 2,
                        "name" : "Phil",
                        "comment" : "Test",
                        "approved" : 1
                },
                {
                        "id" : 3,
                        "name" : "Joe",
                        "comment" : "Test",
                        "approved" : 0
                }
        ],
        "no_comments" : 11,
        "title" : "Hello world"
}
```

If I run the query

```
db.blog.update({'blogid':1}, { $pull : { 'comments' : {'approved' : 0} } });
```

Then it will remove the third comment.

If instead I want to pull all comments where approved is 0 or 1 the following query doesn't work:

```
db.blog.update({'blogid':1}, { $pullAll : { 'comments' : {'approved' : [0,1]} } });
```

I get the error

> Modifier $pushAll/pullAll allowed for
>   arrays only

Can someone please explain where I'm going wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 15):

`$pullAll` requires an exact match. You might use `$pull` instead:

```
{ $pull : { 'comments' : {'approved' : {$in : [0,1]}} } });
```

Comment: So $pullAll does an implicit "AND" of the elements in the value array passed to it versus $pull/$in which does an implicit "OR"? In that case it should be pointed out in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

This is because $pullAll takes array, not an object. I guess follwing code should work:

```
{ $pullAll : { 'comments' : [{'approved' : 1}, {'approved' : 0}] } });
```

Comment: $pullAll requires an exact match

Comment: This won't work as Vasil is correct; see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-825

Answer (score 1):

```
db.blog.update({"blogid":1},{$pullAll:{"comments":{"name":"Phil","comment":{$eq:"Test"}}}})

WriteResult({
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 2,
                "errmsg" : "$pullAll requires an array argument but was given a object"
        }
})

db.blog.update({"blogid":1},{$pull:{"comments":{"name":"Phil","comment":{$eq:"Test"}}}})

WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

**$pull update operator:**

- It works if the element is either array or array with Object.
- It works even if you use any condition operator in query syntax.

**$pullAll update operator:**

- It only works if the element is array.
- It only works if you don't use any condition operator in query syntax